# HTML set User-pasted Image URL as img src

Tags: html, input, image

Okay. I have an image on my website that I would like users to be able to change by pasting a image URL into a text input field and pressing enter. I have the input and image set up, I just don't know how I could take the text that the user pasts into the box, and set it as the img src.

Here is my input

```
<Input type="text" id="usrimg">
```

And here is my Image code I want to change to the URL pasted in the box above

```
imageObj.src = "http://WHATEVERURLUSERPASTES.co";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

javascript?

var imageObj.src = document.getElementById('YOURID').value;

Comment: Wow! I am sure that will work, but how can I get the url to update?

What can I put as my form action?

<form name="input" action="#" method="get">
<input id="usrimg" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

Comment: $("#my_image").attr("src",imageObj.src);

Comment: Do you use any ajax? Where does your submit go?

Comment: Right now I just have my submit going to a refresh #

Comment: and what's your purpose with the form? You want to submit the url to a database and then automatically update the img src or what? If so, just use ajax and change the source upon success

Comment: It's for a final project, and I cannot use Ajax. Only HTML, CSS, and JS.

IS it possible to use OnChange in the Input to update the src?

Answer (score 0):

Server side code? PHP, C#, VB.NET, Vbscript, Jscript, anything usable for CGI?
Pseudo code:

```
var imgobj = (find img)
imgobj.src = query(usrimg)
```